# Prepend line underneath current line (or "join" to front of line)

Tags: join

I'd like to prepend the line below the current line to the current line. In other words, I want to "join" (like with `J` in normal mode) but instead of putting the line below the current line at the end of the current line, I'd like to put it at the front of the current line.

Example:

> ▋lorem ipsum amet dolor
>   blue green orange yellow

becomes

> ▋blue green orange yellow lorem ipsum amet dolor

with the position of the cursor--shown by the solid, black rectangle--at the beginning of the prepended snippet or at its end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use any register, you can do

```
:+m- | normal J
```

or use mapping

```
:nnoremap <leader>J :<c-u>+m-<cr>J
```

`:+m-` is to move the next line to be after the previous line, so eventually the order of the two lines are exchanged.

Comment: Clever use of the rather obscure `:move` command! This solution doesn't clobber the default register like DJMcMayhem's.

Comment: Using `:+m-` to replace `ddpk` has one more benefit: it can be undone using a single `u`. But it cannot be repeated using `.` (`ddpk` cannot be repeated using `.` either)

Answer (score 3):

Just swap the lines before you join them:

```
ddpkJ
```

Of course, if you would like to override `J`'s behavior, you could map this with:

```
:nnoremap J ddpkJ
```

or if you want a new mapping so that you have both options:

```
:nnoremap <leader>J ddpkJ
```